# How to navigate in umbraco

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco, umbraco7

Im new to umbraco, Im using a umbraco surface controller to enter data to database , Normally i use @Html.ActionLink to call to action methods like delete,edit,details etc. Above function cannot be used in umbraco so i want to know how to do that kind of thing in umbraco?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an IPublished item you can just call item.Url inside the href of an anchor tag. this would do the trick.